# cakephp: add filter to a report from dropdown list

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have a report to generate as a view and as an excel file. I am bale to show all its rows in both. The user needs to filter data based on a date field "end_date". In my view, I put this:

```
<?php
            $options = array();
            $options[0] = 'All';
            $options[1] = 'Due last 6 months';
            $options[2] = 'Due current month';
            $options[3] = 'Due next 3 months';
            $options[4] = 'Due next 6 months';
            $options[5] = 'Due next 12 months';            
        ?>

        <div class="row">
            <?= $this->Form->create() ?>
                <fieldset>                    
                    <div class="col-sm-2"><?= $this->Form->input('select_period', array('options' => $options)); ?></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2" style="padding-top:25px;"><?= $this->Form->button('Search', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary']); ?></div>
                </fieldset>
            <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
        </div>
```

in my controller, I use this function:

```
public function reportReplacement()
{
    $assetsAssignations = $this->AssetsAssignations->find()
        ->contain([
            'AssetStatuses',
            'Assets' => [
                'AssetTypes'
                ],
            'Clients' => [
                'ClientTypes'
                ],
        ])
        ->order([
                 'AssetTypes.name' => 'asc',
         ]);
    $filter = $this->Filter->prg($assetsAssignations);
    $_filename = "xls_report_replacement_" . date('Ymd');
    $this->set(compact('assetsAssignations', '_filename'));
}
```

I tried to put this in my controller intialize, but it did not work:

```
if ($this->request->param('action') == 'reportReplacement') {
        $select_period = $this->request->query('select_period'); // I want to get the selected [0], [1], etc..  when I debug, I always get null.
```

I also failed to fin where I have to put the option as a condition in my queries like:

if option[1], then 'end_date' >= (TODAY-6 months) AND 'end_date' <= TODAY;

if option[2], then 'end_date' = TODAY(month);

if option[1], then 'end_date' >= TODAY AND 'end_date' <= (TODAY+3 months);

etc.

any help please ?

Comment: Your initialization of `$select_period` should be in your `reportReplacement` function, not `initialize`. Then you can use it in an `if` or a `switch` to conditionally add whatever `->where` clauses you need to your `$assetsAssignations`.

Comment: thanks Greg. I put it in the function, and the debug always give null:
`$select_period = $this->request->query('select_period');
        debug($select_period);` ---- `$select_period = $this->request->data('select_period');
        debug($select_period);`

Comment: `$this->request->query` is for arguments passed in the query string, not forms. `$this->request->data` is the way to go. Strange that it's not working. What do you get with `debug($this->request->data);`?

Comment: `debug($this->request->data);` gives : [] ---
`die($this->request->data);` gives : Array

Comment: You get this when you're submitting data through the form?

Comment: I get it when I click on the search button in my view : `<div class="row">
            <?= $this->Form->create() ?>
                <fieldset>                    
                    <div class="col-sm-2"><?= $this->Form->input('select_period', array('options' => $options)); ?></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2" style="padding-top:25px;"><?= $this->Form->button('Search', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary']); ?></div>
                </fieldset>
            <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
        </div>`

Comment: What does `debug($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put']));` give you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173575/discussion-between-mbenjemaa-and-greg-schmidt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Greg, I found the solution:

in the view:

```
        <?php
            $options = array();
            $options[0] = 'Due last 6 months';
            $options[1] = 'Due current month';
            $options[2] = 'Due next 3 months';
            $options[3] = 'Due next 6 months';
            $options[4] = 'Due next 12 months';            
        ?>

        <div class="row">
            <?= $this->Form->create() ?>
                <fieldset>                
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><?= $this->Form->input('select_period_id', ['options' => $options, 'empty' => true, 'label' => __('Select Period')]) ?></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2" style="padding-top:25px;"><?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?></div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            <?= $this->Form->end() ?>

        </div>
```

in the controller:

```
use Cake\I18n\Time;
```

and in the function:

```
    $data = $this->request->data;
    $select_period = $this->request->data('select_period_id');
    $today = Time::now()->format('Y-m-d');
    $second_date = Time::now();
    $assetsAssignations = $this->AssetsAssignations->find()
        ->contain(['Assets']);

    if($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) 
    {
        if ($select_period == 0) {                
            $second_date = $second_date->modify('-6 months');                
            $second_date = $second_date->format('Y-m-d');
            $assetsAssignations->where([
                'end_date >=' => $second_date,
                'end_date <=' => $today
                    ]);
        } elseif ($select_period == 1) {
            $second_date = $second_date->modify('1 month');
            $second_date = $second_date->format('Y-m-d');
            $assetsAssignations->where([
                'end_date >=' => $today,
                'end_date <=' => $second_date
                    ]);

        } elseif ($select_period == 2) {
            $second_date = $second_date->modify('3 months');
            $second_date = $second_date->format('Y-m-d');
            $assetsAssignations->where([
                'end_date >=' => $today,
                'end_date <=' => $second_date
                    ]);
        } elseif ($select_period == 3) {
            $second_date = $second_date->modify('6 months');
            $second_date = $second_date->format('Y-m-d');
            $assetsAssignations->where([
                'end_date >=' => $today,
                'end_date <=' => $second_date
                    ]);
        } elseif ($select_period == 4) {
            $second_date = $second_date->modify('12 months');
            $second_date = $second_date->format('Y-m-d');
            $assetsAssignations->where([
                'end_date >=' => $today,
                'end_date <=' => $second_date
                    ]);
        }            
    }

    $this->set(compact('assetsAssignations'));
}
```